# Task.wait not working as I imagined

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am trying to download a file, wait for the file to finish downloading, and then read the file afterwards. I have the following methods to do this:

```
private async Task startDownload(string link, string savePath)
{      
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), savePath);              
}

private void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));
    task.Wait();

    if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        checkVersion();
    }
}
```

The `checkVersion()` method reads the file that was downloaded. This is throwing an `IOException` saying that the file is in use by something else and cannot be read. I thought that having `task.Wait` would prevent the rest of the method from executing until the task was finished?

Comment: Two things: you don't need an await in `StartDownload`, you should just return `client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), savePath);`

Comment: You need to not `Wait` on the task in the UI thread.  You need to `await` it instead.

Comment: @user, please see my answer below. I've tested it and it works and doesn't block the UI thread. If you have questions, please drop a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Wait` will block the current thread (in this case, the UI thread) and wait until the task is completed. In this case, the task is completing with an error, so `Task.Wait` will throw that error wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

As others noted, you should be using `await` instead of `Wait`. Also, `DownloadFileCompleted` doesn't make sense since you're using `DownloadFileTaskAsync` (and not `DownloadFileAsync`); and `StartNew` is unnecessary since the download is asynchronous.

Oh, and let's dispose the `WebClient` and ensure our naming convention follows the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

```
private async Task startDownloadAsync(string link, string savePath)
{      
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), savePath);              
  }
}

private async void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
  await startDownloadAsync(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
  checkVersion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function startDownload is already async, so it's going to start the Task and return right away.  You can use ContinueWith to ensure the task is complete before calling checkVersion().

```
    private void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var task = startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
        task.ContinueWith((x) => checkVersion());
    }
```

An alternative, as Servy points out, would be to use async/await in the Click event.

```
    private async void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
        checkVersion();
    }
```

Comment: Which will of course block the UI thread, freezing the application.

Comment: With your first suggestion, am I changing anything in startDownload? It still returns immediately since the task is async, so it still tries to open the file as it is still downloading it.

Comment: @user2357446 It does return immediately, but it doesn't execute the code until the file is downloaded, using this code.

Comment: @user2357446  You can remove the event handler for DownloadFileCompleted.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to await your `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` call, that way it doesn't block the UI thread.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startDownload("http://www.zwaldtransport.com/images/placeholders/placeholder1.jpg", "" + "sd.jpg"));
}

private async Task startDownload(string link, string savePath)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), savePath);
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
            checkVersion();
    Console.WriteLine("Done, unless error or cancelled.");
}

private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Progress changed.");
}
```

Image placeholder courtesy Google Images and some other website.

Comment: This has the same problem that the OP has, in that you're executing code when you finish starting the task, not when the task that you start finishes.

Comment: The OP should place `checkVersion()` in the DownloadFileCompleted event, if that's what the OP wants. I must have misunderstood.

Comment: That's one option, yes.  Not the best one though.