# Continuous Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to figure out how to properly chain tasks together. So far I have the following:

```
Task taskExe = new Task(() => startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo));
Task taskVersionTxt = taskExe.ContinueWith((t) => startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));
Task taskWriteVersion = taskVersionTxt.ContinueWith((t) => writeNewVersion());
taskExe.Start();
```

This doesn't work the way I imagined because `writenNewVersion` requires that the first 2 tasks be finished so that it can modify the file that was downloaded.

Here is `startDownload`

```
private async Task startDownload(string link, string savePath)
{                              
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), savePath);                    
}
```

What is the proper way to chain 3 tasks together that wait for the previous task to finish?

Comment: Is this pre-.Net 4.5?

Comment: Negative. This is .NET 4.5

Comment: You can just use async/await instead of `ContinueWith`

Comment: @user1806716: You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Why did you create a new account to [post a new version of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451392/task-wait-not-working-as-i-imagined/25452685#25452685)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startDownload` is *already* asynchronous.  Starting it in a new thread is creating a task who's sole job is to start a new task.  You would see this more clearly if you looked at the actual types of your variables:

Here is what their real types are:

```
Task<Task> taskExe = new Task(() => 
    startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo));
Task<Task> taskVersionTxt = taskExe.ContinueWith((t) => 
    startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));
Task<Task> taskWriteVersion = taskVersionTxt.ContinueWith((t) => 
    writeNewVersion());
```

Your tasks are complete *when you finish starting the asynchronous operations*, not when those operations actually complete.  You need to wait until the wrapped task completes, not the outer task, by `Unwrap`-ing it.  Or, for that matter, just don't wrap the task needlessly in the first place.

```
Task taskExe = startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo);
Task taskVersionTxt = taskExe.ContinueWith((t) => 
    startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo))
    .Unwrap();
Task taskWriteVersion = taskVersionTxt.ContinueWith((t) => 
    writeNewVersion())
    .Unwrap();
```

Of course, using `await` is simpler:

```
await startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo);
await startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
await writeNewVersion();
```

Comment: I got rid of the needless wrapping and the code works, but it still seems like the two downloads are running at the same time. Ideally I should see the progress for the first download, a pause, and then the progress for the second one.

Comment: @user1806716 There is going to be a delay between when the downloader indicates that there is progress and when the event handler that is listening to it gets scheduled to run and performs whatever UI operation you have.  If the operation is fast enough, that short scheduling delay could be longer than the entirety of the first operation.  You could add in your own delay using `Task.Delay` to intentionally stall the application for some more noticeable amount of time if you wanted.

Comment: I see, would I add the Task.Delay to the second and third tasks?

Comment: @user1806716 If you want to have a delay after the first operation finishes and before the second starts, put a delay there.  If you want a delay after the second finishes and before the third starts, put a delay there.  If you want a delay somewhere else, put it there.

Comment: What I meant was that if I put Task.Delay(1000) inside of startDownload(), I get the same result, they both download at the "same time." Same thing if I put Time.Delay(1000) between taskExe and taskVersionTxt.

Comment: @user1806716 Did you `await` it?

Comment: Duh, not sure why I didn't notice I didn't await it. I got it working now :). It waits 2 seconds between each download. Thanks @Servy!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use `async`/`await`, the process is quite straightforward. Start the first two operations to run in parallel, then use `await Task.WhenAll(...)` to wait for them to both complete.

```
public async Task RunOperationAsync()
{
    List<Task> downloads = new List<Task>();
    downloads.Add(startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo));
    downloads.Add(startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));
    await Task.WhenAll(downloads);

    await writeNewVersion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using both tasks and async.  If you take async off of your startDownload method, it should work, or if you stop using tasks.  You're making it async in 2 different ways, and then only synchronizing one of them, and expecting it to be synchronous.

In LINQPad, this works as expected:

```
void Main()
{
    string downloadLink = "dl", saveTo = "st", versionLink = "vl", versionSaveTo = "vst";
    Task taskExe = new Task(() => startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo));
    Task taskVersionTxt = taskExe.ContinueWith((t) => startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));
    Task taskWriteVersion = taskVersionTxt.ContinueWith((t) => writeNewVersion());
    taskExe.Start();
}

void startDownload(string dl, string st)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ("Download done: " + dl + " " + st).Dump();
}

void writeNewVersion()    
{
    "Version done".Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task RunOperationAsync()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        startDownload(downloadLink, saveTo),
        startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo));

    await writeNewVersion();
}
```

Comment: @Servy: You're right; the synchronous part of `startDownload` is trivial, and doesn't justify the overhead of spawning it off onto a new task.

Comment: Your last edit made your answer incorrect; it was correct before the edit.